# Define association using database column and not entity type property

Tags: ef-code-first, fluent-interface

```
public class Order {
   public int OrderID {get; set;}
   public DateTime DateOrdered { get; set; }
   public ICollection<OrderLine> OrderLines { get; set; }
}

public class OrderLine{
    public int OrderLineID { get; set; }
    public int OrderID {get; set; } // I want to remove this
    public string ItemName { get; set;}
    public Int Qty { get; set; }
}
```

How would I map these using the Fluent API? I am using these in a repository pattern where `Order` will be the root of the aggregate. As such I do not want OrderLine to have a reference to `Order` or have an `OrderID`. Since the `OrderLine` only makes any sense because its a child of `Order`.

Currently I am using this:

```
HasMany<OrderLine>(x => x.OrderLines).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(x => x.OrderID);
```

I am using an existing database structure here and ideally I would map this using the database column name. So somehow tell it to use `tblOrderLine.colOrderId` rather then `OrderLine.OrderID`.

Comment: That would remove the part of PK in `OrderLine` class. Whats the PK on `OrderLine` table?

Comment: OrderLine has an OrderLineID as the PK. I'll adjust above to reflect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Map()` method to map your FK

```
HasMany<OrderLine>(x => x.OrderLines)
.WithRequired()
.Map(m => m.MapKey("colOrderId"));
```